# Executing onclick when ondrop event of <li>

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, drag-and-drop, onclick

I have a `<li>` and I want to know if there is a way to execute a code behind click function on the ondrop event of that `<li>`.

And on that onclick event I want to force a postback any idea of that too?

This is a repeater by the way.

Here is my `<li>`

```
<li id="litDashboard" ondrop="btnSave_Click" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <span>Hello!</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

I don't know if you need this but this is my `<ul>` also the area where the user can drag and drop items.

```
<ul id="ulSortableDashboard">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a but vague.
Do you want the event to be client side or server side?
You can add a button inside the < li > 
and give it some code you want to run

If you are using a repeater you can give the button's commands by using
OnItemCommand="RepData_ItemCommand" in the repeater like

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepData" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepData_ItemCommand">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSave" Text="Save" CommandName="Saved"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

with the folowing code on your server side

```
       protected void RepData_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
       {
        string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString();

        if (commandName == "Saved")//this is if btnsave is clicked
        {
              //your code here
        }
```